# Mix shell command in environment conda with python scripts in snakemake tool

Tags: python-3.x, shell, while-loop, yaml, snakemake

I would like to mix shell command in environment conda with any Python scripts, so the use of the 'run' section isn't possible ...

I tried :

```
shell:"""
   gunzip -c {input.ech} | NanoFilt -l {params.min_length} --maxlength {params.max_length} -s {input.summary} -q {params.q} --readtype {params.rd} | gzip > Working_space_ont/01_nanofilt/{wildcards.sample}_filt_{params.q}.fastq.gz   
   python3 reinit.py
   while [[ -f Working_space_ont/01_nanofilt/{wildcards.sample}_filt_{params.q}.fastq.gz ]] && [[ grep -c '>' Working_space_ont/01_nanofilt/{wildcards.sample}_filt_{params.q}.fastq.gz < {params.cov} ]]; do
       python3 quality_minor.py
       gunzip -c {input.ech} | NanoFilt -l {params.min_length} --maxlength {params.max_length} -s {input.summary} -q {params.q} --readtype {params.rd} | gzip > Working_space_ont/01_nanofilt/{wildcards.sample}_filt_{params.q}.fastq.gz
   done
   mv Working_space_ont/01_nanofilt/{wildcards.sample}_filt_{params.q}.fastq.gz {output} 
"""
```

I have non-zero exit status 1 error

reinit.py :

```
import yaml

with open("config_wf.yaml") as f:
    old_yaml = yaml.load(f)

old_yaml["params"]["filtration"]["quality"] = old_yaml["params"]["filtration"]["quality_fix"]  

with open("config_wf.yaml", 'w') as f:
    yaml.dump(old_yaml, f, default_flow_style=False)
```

quality_minor.py :

```
import yaml

with open("config_wf.yaml") as f:
    old_yaml = yaml.load(f)

old_yaml["params"]["filtration"]["quality"] -= 1

with open("config_wf.yaml", 'w') as f:
    yaml.safe(old_yaml, f, default_flow_style=False)
```

Do you have any ideas for me? 
Best Regards, 

Eva

Comment: Are you rewriting the file `"Working_space_ont/01_nanofilt/{wildcards.sample}_filt_{params.q}.fastq.gz"` intentianally?

Comment: Yes, because, I want to create this file and to control it after : if its content is too poor, I would like rerun the command with a lower threshold ..

Comment: when its content was acceptable, I thought to move it in a directory Working_space_ont/01_nanofilt/**PASS**/{wildcards.sample}_filt_{params.q}.fastq.gz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your python scripts are altering the config yaml for the workflow and not passing that directly to the nanofilt command.  Are you getting an infinite loop then?  The config yaml is read at the start the snakemake process so altering it in a rule should have no effect.

You may be able to achieve this through snakemake using attempts in an input function to the params where each failure decrements the parameter and a job fails when the filtering is bad.

A cleaner solution would be to write a python script that would use nanofilt as a library and wrap its execution.  The [main method](https://github.com/wdecoster/nanofilt/blob/master/nanofilt/NanoFilt.py#L33) is straight forward.  Build up your args and adjust as needed then all the evaluation code and loops will be in python.

Comment: To modify the config file is a very bad idea.
Thank you for your interest in my post. At my level, I just manage to export the changing parameters in a temporary file for each sample.

But maybe in the future I'll be able to do it for a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 0):

Snakemake shell doesn't support bash syntax for loops. I see two possible solutions.

First, you may wrap this code into a *.sh* file and run that from the `shell` section:

```py
shell: "run.sh"
```

Next, you may run each command with the `shell` function from the `run` section:

```py
run:
    shell("""gunzip -c {input.ech} | NanoFilt -l {params.min_length} --maxlength {params.max_length} -s {input.summary} -q {params.q} --readtype {params.rd} | gzip > Working_space_ont/01_nanofilt/{wildcards.sample}_filt_{params.q}.fastq.gz""")
    shell("python3 reinit.py")
    # Implement your logic in Python
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you ! it's not solved yet but it's better : ) 
The first solution is ok for me, passing by script shell, I can to do loop. 
The second solution, I had tried it but the run section not allowed the --use-conda fllag to run NanoFilt ..  
Have a good day,